# Scala windowing data with Akka HTTP

Tags: java, scala, akka, drools, akka-http

I am using Akka HTTP to send data in post request and accumulating it in a list. I need to execute some rules on that data which will do aggregation on batches. To create batches, I need to windowing the data for fixed times

Data which I have in List is something like,

```
 data = List(
  Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0,"time" -> 12345678293), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 40.0, "d" -> 2.0,"time" -> 12345678293), Map("a" -> 4.0, "b" -> 267.0, "c" -> 26.0, "d" -> 2.0,"time" -> 12345678293), Map("a" -> 1.0, "b" -> 2678.0, "c" -> 90.0, "d" -> 17.0,"time" -> 12345678293),...
  )
```

time is in the epoch provided

This list will keep on increasing with time

My rules are like

```
 RuleName   function   WindowTime
   R1         sum(a)      5 Min
   R2         avg(b)      10 Min
   R3         StdDev(d)   30 Min
   ...         ...         ...
```

and so on

ignore function column, for now, My question is I have around 200 rules like this, which have different window times. How to create and manage so many different windows? How to trigger event, so that rules execute on its time

As per the above example, Rule R1 will execute after every 5 mins, and R2 in every 10 Mins, So, until all rules don't execute I can't expire data also. Notice, when R2 will execute R1 will also execute, as R1 has completed 5 mins and R2 has completed 10 mins.

I am purely using Scala, Akka.

I went through the drools also, but I don't know how drools manage so many rules with different windows.

Any idea and help are appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems like a use case for Iteratee pattern. But Streams can also be a rough solution. Drools is useful only for "rule representation" and "rule execution". Your problem is more about the function of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can store data somewhere (db, in memory, etc) and configure [akka scheduler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scheduler.html) to invoke specific calculations with some interval
2. you can easily compose needed calculations using akka-stream graphs (akka-http stream + broadcast + groupedWithin flow), but this might be overuse of streams

Comment: if i will use akka scheduler, then how to manage data offsets and how to discard old data... as every rule will consume different windows